# preferred way of creating models classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in MVC, I would like to hear your opinion on how you create classes as Models.

Say, I have:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Would you rather put `Person` and `Address` in the same file or separate them? What I'm trying to say is, would you rather put classes related to each other in a single file or separate them and make a different file for each class? I know this isn't much of a big issue but I would like to hear your thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about view models or domain entities? It is important to understand the difference.

Comment: 1 class per file is the convention (sparing nested classes); this has nothing to do with MVC however

Comment: Personally I would seperate them, an address isn't a person. If you have an extented class for Person, then I would put that class in your persons file.

Comment: @DanPantry what do you mean sparing nested classes? would you mind putting them in the answer section, I would like to mark it as a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would separate your classes out to the one-class-per-file convention. This has nothing to do with MVC, though. The only exception would be nested types - these are types that are 'nested' within another class. In this case it makes more sense to put them in the same file as their parent class. For example,

```
// BaseEntity.cs
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    ....
}


// Person.cs
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    ....
}

// Address.cs
public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    ....
}
```

All of those would be in separate files, however let's say we had a nested type of StreetAddress, which is a struct; I would put this inside of Address (this is a **very** contrived example)

```
// Address.cs
public class Address : BaseEntity
{
    public StreetAddress Street { get; set; }

    public struct StreetAddress
    {
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
    }
}
```